# JSF. How to disable page components by bean method

Tags: jsf, primefaces, menuitem

I want to disable some menuitem on my web page:

```
<p:menuitem value="Edit" update=":formedit:viewDisplayEdit" icon="ui-icon-document" oncomplete=... disabled="#{bean.ask(1)}"/>
```

And in my backup bean:

```
public boolean ask(int id)
{
Ask the database here for privilege "id" and return true if logged user have privilege "id" 
else return false
}
```

Of course I'd like to check it only once - during the rendering of the page.
In this example, regardless of the result of the method "ask" menuitem is always enabled.
I know that I can set the boolean variable xmls code (#{bean.ask1}), but I would like a universal solution.
Could you help?

Comment: It is always enabled because as per your code disabled will be false always. On what condition you want it to disable and enable?

Comment: I have about 20-30 different menuitems, buttons, etc. on some pages. I read my privileges from database and want to enable or disable some activites on page. So, my "id" param for ask function is the "id" of privilege. In place "//here I check the id and return result" there should be: "Ask my database for ID privilege for logged user and return result true or false".

Comment: Stupid mistake! There should be negation before: disabled="#{!bean.ask(1)}"

Answer (score 0):

Make ask a private variable in the bean with get and set methods.

```
private boolean ask = true;

public boolean isAsk(){
    return ask;
}

public void setAsk(boolean ask){
    this.ask = ask;
}
```

Now for whatever condition you want to enable or disable the menu item, set or reset the ask variable appropriately in a different method in the bean.

```
if (condition = true){
    setAsk(false);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But I have sometimes about 20 different actions on each page and I can't create so many variables in each bean. I need the universal method in my bean super class.